# static variable load process

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jvm, vm-implementation

Recently, I research how virtual machine load static variable, but I encounter a problem as follows:

```
public class Example{

    static{
        num = 3;
        System.out.print(num);
    }
    public static int num;
}
```

The compiler reports an error. I think the `num` has memory area and value. Why can't I access `num` variable?

Comment: Put `public static int num;` above the block (Cannot reference a field before it is defined). I don't know if it's a typo, but you forgot to write `int`.

Comment: - 1 for your code does not compile, but you claim a runtime error, and do not tell which one.

Comment: Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`static` blocks and declarations are executed *in the order they are coded*. This means that at the time the static block executes, the `num` field is not yet defined.

The simple fix is moving the declaration *above* the block.

The [Java Language Specification Section 8.3.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3) (among other things) says that a variable may *assigned* a value *before* being declared, but the value of the variable may not be *accessed* before the variable is declared **unless its name is fully qualified**, so this compiles:

```
public class Example {
    static{
        num = 3; // assignment OK without qualifying the name
        System.out.print(Example.num); // name must be qualified to access value
    }
    public static int num;
}
```

---

Still more interesting is that if a variable is accessed before being declared, its *default* value is used, and further the initialization on declaration *still occurs*, so this code:

```
public class Example {
    static{
        System.out.println(Example.num); // uses default value
        num = 3;                         // assignment OK
        System.out.println(Example.num); // assigned value (3) is visible
    }

    public static int num = 1;           // initialization to 1 occurs

    static{
        System.out.print(Example.num);   // initialized value (1) is visible 
    }
}
```

Produces this output:

```
0
3
1
```

Wow!

Comment: I read the article about how virtual machine load class process.I think the num's symbolic reference in class file has been loaded in virtual machine,so the num variable has been declared.Do I misunderstand?

Comment: Cool,I understand your explanation!But could you please explain why I can use fully qualified of a static variable to access it?Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KrystalJake It's defined in the language specification (one "explanation"), the reason for which I could hazard a guess that since the field isn't technically defined, the qualification allows the compile to create an accurate placeholder for the actual field